# Javascript / Nodered function node: bitstream operations

Tags: javascript, node-red, bitstream

Following task to do:

There is a protocol that defines minimalistic data like:

```
binary     0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
variable   [-] [-----] [---] [-------]
name       a      b      c       d
```

where parameter "a" consists of 2 bits, parameter "b" of 5 bits and so on. I have to set them like

```
a=1
b=1
c=6
d=...
```

so the above bit buffer will automatically result.

This stream of bits shall be stored in a buffer like this:

```
let buf = Buffer.alloc(64, 0);
```

Is there a possibility to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to this.

1. Using nodes like the [node-red-contrib-buffer-parser](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-buffer-parser) which will allow you to do this as part of a flow
2. Do basic [bit shifting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift) in function nodes. e.g.

   ```
   var a = 1
   var b = 16
   var c = 2
   var d = 10

   var answer  = a << 14 | b << 12 | c << 10 | d << 6
   ```

   which can then be written to a [buffer.writeUint16()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#bufwriteuint16bevalue-offset)

Comment: Great new node! Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I will try the node-red-contrib-buffer-parser thing but it looks good!